# Jquery Tabs Flash Color and Fade out to another color

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Ok my issue is that i have JQuery Tabs. and the content on each changes dynamically. I would like the tab on the ones that change to change to a Bright Red color then fade to another color. But on focus change back to the original color.

Is there an easy way to do this?

this is a functional Sample... remember that there will be a datatable on each tab panel. I have each panel and tabs with unique ID's a better way then that because that way can be broken.

when you click the first button it will add the tabs... the second button is where i want to activate the colored tab flash as if it was the event that triggered it...

Please do not go off of the convention of tab id  `#ui-id-1`

this is not how i reference the tabs

http://jsfiddle.net/alfredmey/8ny27Ljf/2/

Comment: Are you using ajax to load? Can you provide the code you have so far? I can write something for you if I have a bit more info

Comment: added a sample to JSFiddle

Comment: @BigAlRubyNewbie it is a good practice to add some code to your question.  Please read our Help section on how to create an  MCVE
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.
You will get faster, better help from the community that way.

Comment: I just added a whole JSFiddle to this

Comment: what I meant was that for  a question to be 'self-sufficient' it is recommended practice to add actual code to the question (here in SO)  - a fiddle is great but if the fiddle is down, no one can see what the issue actually is - or help you with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for but this will highlight the active tab.

You can add it to your `.click(...)` event handler (before the alert is shown in your fiddle) to see it work.

```
 $("#search-tabs ul li.ui-state-active").effect( 'highlight', 2000);
```

If you want to highlight any tab (not just the active one) you can use this selector instead  (replacing `ui-id-1` on the callback as needed)

```
$("#search-tabs ul li[aria-labelledby='ui-id-1'").effect( 'highlight', 2000);
```

To change the colour to something other than 'yellow' you can call the effect like this

`$(...).effect( 'highlight', {color: '#aa0000'}, 2000);`

**Updated below based on comments**

If you want, you can add the highlight effect on tab activation by adding it right after the 'active' option (creation time) like this:

```
"activate": function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.newTab[0]).effect( 'highlight', {color: 'yellow', }, 1000);
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ny27Ljf/4/)

**One more Update**

If you do not want to simply 'highlight' the tab but permanently change the colour of it, use `.animate(...)` instead

```
$(<selector>).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
      color: "#fff" }, 1000 );
```

Then, to revert back to the original colours (when active or `clicked` on), you could:

```
$(<selector>).animate({
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          color: "#aa0000" }, 1000 );
```

Comment: The thing is these tabs are Dynamic. and not sure what the ui-id-# because there might be 10 - 15 tabs open... and everyone of them have a different table

Comment: Is there a way to get the parent Id (tab ID) if i go from the table id and go out

Comment: When exactly are you triggering the effect? on the callback function?

Comment: @BigAlRubyNewbie yes there is... but you need to tell me when you are thinking of invoking this functionality... I can think of a way to make it dynamic like that

Comment: Sorry for late response.. I am gonna have a loop function that checks the last 5 minutes of post every 5 min. and when there is a match it will trigger the javascript that adds the row to the table and triggers this.

Comment: There may be 10 - 15 tabs open and everyone of them will have a unique table ID in the ui-tab-panel and this will have to flash the right tab even if it isnt the active tab.

Comment: In that case, add the 'effect' on the callback function... How are you adding a row to a table when there is a match?  in the same javascript function that does that, at the very end  you can add the line to trigger the effect.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah that is where i will add it but what you have is highlight. I would like it to Highlight the fade to another color and stay on that color until the user clicks on that tab..(focus) then it can go back to white

Comment: Ok, then `.effect(...)` will not help in this case... You may want to `.animate(...)` -- see my latest update on the answer